# Does the Google Spanner Emulator work with the Google Spanner JDBC Driver?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have tried this isn [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) and [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/).

Running with the Google Spanner Emulator locally (0.8.0)

```
export SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9010

Executing: docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9010:9010 -p 127.0.0.1:9020:9020 gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator:0.8.0
[cloud-spanner-emulator] 2020/07/17 22:23:21 gateway.go:135: Cloud Spanner emulator running.
[cloud-spanner-emulator] 2020/07/17 22:23:21 gateway.go:136: REST server listening at 0.0.0.0:9020
[cloud-spanner-emulator] 2020/07/17 22:23:21 gateway.go:137: gRPC server listening at 0.0.0.0:9010
```

Will this work with the [Google JDBC Spanner Driver](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/jdbc-drivers)?

In my testing, my guess is:

*No this is not currently supported.*

I can manage to connect to a GCP instance of spanner, but not the emulator. When I try with port 9010 or 9020 it basically hangs.

My jdbc connection strings are as follows (the project, instance and the database have all been created):

```
gcloud spanner databases list --project=local-project --instance=local-instance --configuration=spanner-emulator --format json

[
  {
    "name": "projects/local-project/instances/local-instance/databases/myDatabase",
    "state": "READY"
  },
]
```

```
# 9010
jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost:9010/projects/local-project/instances/local-instance/databases/myDatabase

# 9020
jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost:9020/projects/local-project/instances/local-instance/databases/myDatabase

# just the host
jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost/projects/local-project/instances/local-instance/databases/myDatabase
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emulator does not use TLS, while the JDBC driver will use that by default. You can turn off TLS for the JDBC driver by setting the `usePlainText` connection property to `true`. The following connection URL should work:

```
jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost:9010/projects/local-project/instances/local-instance/databases/myDatabase?usePlainText=true
```